# How to sort a list using Jane Core?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I'm trying to achieve this

```
open Core
let%test _ = List.sort ~cmp:Int.compare [1;2;3] = [1;2;3]
```

But it fails with

```
61 | let%test _ = List.sort ~cmp:Int.compare [1;2;3] = [1;2;3]
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: The function applied to this argument has type
         compare:('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list
This argument cannot be applied with label ~cmp
```

Okay I find out. The problem was that googling for *ocaml core list* lead me to outdated docs. The label name is `~compare`

So this works

```
let%test _ = List.sort ~compare:Int.compare [1;2;3] = [1;2;3]
```

The *latest* docs: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/ (this may not be what you're searching, you can find other versions at https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/)

Comment: You might want to move your edit to a self-answer for future readers.

Comment: I've pushed your own answer (slightly reworded) into a proper answer so that other users of SO could also benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Janestreet Core library is changing its interface with time. The old name of the keyword parameter was `cmp` and it was changed to `compare` for the consistency with the other parts of the library,

```
 let%test _ = List.sort ~compare:Int.compare [1;2;3] = [1;2;3]
```

- The latest docs: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/
- Older versions could be found here: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/
  (this may not be what you're searching, you can find other versions at )